# How can I refer to multiple .bib files by explicitly specifying their full path address?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, paths

I use the Natbib package for bibliography management. Usually, my `.tex` files are somewhere in my `c:\\` drive, but I would like to keep my `.bib` files in my Google Drive, which creates a virtual drive on my machine as `G:\My Drive\`. Please note that there is a space in `My Drive`, and I cannot get rid of this because it is automatically created by Google Drive. My question is how can I **explicitly** specify the path address to my `.bib` files in my `.tex` files?

Note 1: When I provide the full address inside `\bibliography` it does not work, possibly because of the space in my address. It does not work even when I wrap the whole address with quotation marks.

Note 2: I had a similar issue with referring to my figures, but `\graphicspath` from the `graphicx` package solved the issue because it allows me to explicitly refer to my `G:\\` drive, which also includes my figures.

Note 3: I updated the question after having the discussion with
@David Carlisle Below.

Comment: you can put that folder in your BIBINPUTS path or just give the full path in `\bibliography` same as any other folder

Comment: For me, \bibliography can find the .bib file only if it is located in the same folder as my .tex file. If I give the full path in \bibliography, it cannot populate the citations. Could it be a WinEdt issue?

How can I specify the BIBINPUTS path?

Comment: winedt is just the editor so not involved but I'd expect `\bbliography{g:/whatever/ref1}` to find `g:\whatever\ref1.bib`

Comment: I have already tried this and it does not work. One possible issue that I can think of is that the folder that Google Drive creates is G:\My Drive\ [the rest of the address]. Please note that there is a space in "My Drive". To address this issue, I have also wrapped the whole address in quotation marks but still does not work.

I mentioned WinEdt just to rule out the possibility that it has got something to do with its settings. 

One

Comment: I moved my ```.bib``` file to ```c:\``` and I could provide the full address in ```\bibliography```, as you suggested, David Carlisle. So, the problem is related to the ```G:/``` drive that I cannot provide the full address when my ```.bib``` files are in ```G```. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: possibly bibtex isn't causing the drive to sync so the file isn't "really" there yet sorry I don't have a windows bibtex to test try `\bibliography{ref`}`  after settig BIBINPUTS  to ` G:\My Drive\ [the rest of the address]. ` in the environment

Comment: No, unfortunately, it did not work.